# Azure The deployment name '' does not exist Java Create VM

Tags: java, azure, deployment, virtual-machine

I'm trying to deploy a VM using the Azure Java SDK. I am able to retrieve listings from my Azure portal through Java.

When trying to deploy the VM it asks for a Deployment Name in the function:

computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations().create(String, String, VirtualMachineCreateParameters);

The second string is supposed to be Deployment Name, where can I find what this should be in the Azure portal or how do I create the deployment name container?

I've tried several names I thought might be correct and get the exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ResourceNotFound: The deployment name 'thundertest' does not exist.
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.create(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:5359)
    at com.thunderhead.cloudlib.azure.RequestBuilder.createVirtualMachines(RequestBuilder.java:344)
    at com.thunderhead.cloudlib.azure.RequestBuilder.main(RequestBuilder.java:365)
Caused by: com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException: ResourceNotFound: The deployment name '<deploymentName?>' does not exist.
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.exception.ServiceException.createFromXml(ServiceException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.beginCreating(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:1884)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl$3.call(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:1038)
    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.management.compute.VirtualMachineOperationsImpl$3.call(VirtualMachineOperationsImpl.java:1035)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Did you try calling `computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations().createDeployment()` first?

Comment: I did not, I'll try that and report back. I'm having a hard time finding any comprehensive documentation on the java sdk.

Comment: I hear you on that.  Their [unit tests](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/management-compute/src/test/java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/management/compute/VirtualMachineOperationsTests.java#L276) might provide some basic usage examples.

Comment: The unit tests are what has gotten me this far but they are a bit cryptic. Thanks for the pointer that got me past that issue, on to the next one!

Comment: Ah, thanks for the heads up, could you post as an answer and I'll upvote it? I deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations().createDeployment()` first should give you a deployment object who's name you can pass to `computeManagementClient.getVirtualMachinesOperations().create`.